# Prove that, if all perfect matchings in G are pairwise disjoint, than every two perfect matchings contain the edge set of a hamiltonian cycle in G.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I have no idea how to prove this one. It looks like common sense, but I don't know hot to proceed with the proof.

Comment: Maybe you can start with trying to put into words why exactly you feel that it is common sense and we can work from there...

Comment: Perfect matching means that every vertex of the graph is incident to exactly one edge of the matching, so if there are two disjoint perfect matchings, that means in every matching the vertices are incident to different edges. Hamilton cycle means a graph cycle through a graph that visits each node exactly once. So it ´s logical to think that the two perfect matchings contain the egde set.

Answer (score 2):

Think it through in two steps:

1. What does the union of two disjoint perfect matchings $M_1 \cup M_2$ look like *in general*?
2. If that union is not a Hamiltonian cycle, can you find inside it a third perfect matching $M_3$ different from both $M_1$ and $M_2$? (Yes, you can; how?)

Because if you can, then $M_3$ is certainly not disjoint from either $M_1$ or $M_2$, and so not all matchings are pairwise disjoint.

Conversely, if all matchings *are* pairwise disjoint, then we can never find this $M_3$, which means that $M_1 \cup M_2$ must be a Hamiltonian cycle.